# Migrate to Entity Framework, use of datatables and stored procedures

Tags: .net, entity-framework, stored-procedures, datatable

I'm in the process of rebuilding an ado.net supported web site to use Entity Framework.

Currently I have a stored procedure returning address details which I store in a datatable. Simplified columns breakdown like this, and queries return multiple rows. In reality I have around 15 columns coming back, and normally 2-3 rows.

- AddressID
- HouseNo
- Street
- Town
- City
- YearsAtAddress
- MonthsAtAddress

Within the application code I then transpose the rows and columns in the datatable and then bind to a gridview. When it displays on screen, my columns run top to bottom and each one of the returned rows goes left to right on screen.

This gives me two useful advantages

1. I can easily change the stored proc to add/remove data columns, and the application code dynamically handles the new data, just adding/removing items to the bottom of the list
2. I never get more rows than the page width could handle, but it's flexible enough to nicely handle single or multiple addresses.

Is there anyway I can replicate this using entity framework? I'd like to continue to use data tables but not found much online, and I guess mixing EF and ADO.Net is probably not best?

Since the returned EF is a strongly typed object, I'm looking to avoid having to have a large number of labels to display each object property manually, preferring for the bound gridview to do the hard work dynamically.

Thanks

Comment: The **whole point of EF** is that you **don't need** to mess around with untyped rows and columns anymore, but your relational model gets translated into **nice, useful .NET objects** (and collections of such objects) instead.

Comment: Could you point me in the right direction for what I'm trying to do? I'm in no doubt that EF is the way to go, and I hope there is a solution to my problem. They key problem I seem to have this time is swapping a X by Y dataset into a Y by X dataset and bind it to gridview. If I don't transpose my data I get a very wide but very short data grid, which I can't have.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `PIVOT` to do the row/column transposition in the stored procedure before returning the result set. This does mean you'll need to alter the PIVOT code when the sproc changes.

There's also nothing wrong with just leaving ADO.NET in if you want to do that. If you are using stored procedures you are already outside the realms of "pure" EF and that's fine. It makes the app slightly less portable but you still get most of the advantages of using EF.